# Are all one-dimensional projective varieties over the complex field orientable?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, algebraic-number-theory

I have learned some knowledges as follows. Elliptic curves over complex fields are topologically homeomorphic with a torus. Projective spaces $\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{C})$ is orientable and has genus 0. Projective Plane $\mathbb{P}^2(\mathbb{R})$ is non orientable and has genus 1. One dimensional smooth projective varieties over complex fields are compact Riemannian surfaces. Therefore, I have a question: are all one-dimensional projective varieties over the complex field orientable? If the answser is no, is there a counterexample?

Comment: Yes. In fact, any complex manifold is canonically oriented. In one dimension, if $v$ is a nonzero element of the real  tangent space at a point, then $v,iv$ gives a positively oriented basis.

Comment: Your sentence "One dimensional projective varieties over complex fields are compact Riemannian surfaces" is actually wrong (you forgot to add "smooth"). The question itself, belongs to MSE, not MO.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thanks for your help. Excuse me, can you tell me what is "MSE" and "MO"?

Comment: @DonuArapura Thanks for your help.

Comment: MO means this website, Math Overflow, which is for research level questions, whereas MSE is our sister site, Math Stack Exchange, which is simpler maths questions.

Comment: @Moishe Kohan @ Harry Wilson
 Haha, thanks!